# Need to take data from text file to spreadsheet for analysis

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-3.x

I am working with data which I get in text files, and which has to be subsequently analysed. I'm currently using Excel for this task. The original file looks like this:

```
Contact Angle (deg)     86.20
Wetting Tension (dy/cm)     4.836
Wetting Tension Left (dy/cm)    39.44
Wetting Tension Right (dy/cm)   39.44
Base Tilt Angle (deg)       0.00
Base (mm)           1.6858
Base Area (mm2)         2.2322
Height (mm)         0.7888
Tip Width (mm)          0.9707
Wetted Tip Width (mm)       0.9581
Sessile Volume (ul)     1.1374
Sessile Surface Area (mm2)  4.1869
Contrast (cts)          245
Sharpness (cts)         161
Black Peak (cts)        10
White Peak (cts)        255
Edge Threshold (cts)        111
Base Left X (mm)        4.138
Base Right X (mm)       5.821
Base Y (mm)         2.980
RMS Fit Error (mm)      3.545E-3
@1600
```

I don't need the majority of this information, and for now, all I need is the Contact Angle at the top, and the time (prefixed by the '@' at the bottom). At the moment, I have a script which extracts the information I need and creates another text file for easy reading. The code used is below:

```
infile = "in.txt"
outfile = "newout.out"
measure_time = ""
with open(infile) as f, open(outfile, 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
        if line.split():
            if line.split()[0] == "Contact":
                contact_angle = line.split()[-1].strip()
                f2.write("Contact Angle (deg): " + contact_angle + '\n')
            if line.split()[0][0] == '@':
                for i in range(1,5):
                    measure_time += (line.split()[0][i])
                f2.write("Measured at: " + measure_time[:2] + ":" + measure_time[2:] + '\n')
            measure_time = ""
        else:
            continue
```

What I am looking for is a way to get my data nicely formatted in a spreadsheet for easy analysis. I would like the angles in the same row, in adjoining cells, and the measurement time in the cells below that, but I'm unsure what the best way to go about this is.

Can anyone with some more Python experience help me here?

EDIT: The image here shows what I tried to explain (poorly) above.[image: Sample of what I'm looking to achieve]

EDIT2: The solution posted below by @RonRosenfeld works, but I would still prefer to have a Python solution for this problem, as stated earlier. As I have no previous experience with Excel VBA, I would rather use something familiar to me.

Comment: Could you add a quick sketch or image of what Excel output you would want with the data you provided? Then we can show you some code to accomplish those results.

Comment: Check out a .NET language or VB Script (you don't need to install anything for that one), using .net libraries with these languages can achieve tight integration into Microsoft Office, and almost everything is built in.

Comment: @JohnDorian I've added an image to the original post. Something along these lines is what I want. The original text files are usually quite long, so I want to read the angle and measurement time of the first block of text, then move to a new column for the next block, etc... Does this help?

Comment: @Matthew I edited my answer below so as to account for the layout you show in your image.  I also converted your time value into a "real" Excel time, and formatted as you show above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just read the original file or files into Excel, selecting only those lines that begin with the Contact Angle, or @ token.  I'm not sure how much error checking you need to do.  The following assumes that you will select multiple files, and that each file is formatted as you demonstrated in your original data.  It will output the angles in row 1, and the corresponding times in row 2.  It does NOT check for proper formatting; or that every Angle has a corresponding Time.

It also does NOT test and will give an error, if you only select one file.  That capability can be added, if necessary.

**EDIT:** *modified to account for either **TAB** or **SPACE** as the separator; also added code to clear worksheet and autofit the columns*

It should also be easy to modify if you want to select additional parameters.

```
    Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub GetDataFromTextFiles()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim F As File
    Dim sLines As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sFilePath
    Dim S As String
    Dim vLines() As Variant
    Dim rExtract As Range
'Hard Coded here but could also use a
'User form to select multiple lines
vLines = Array("@", "Contact Angle")
Set rExtract = [b3]
Cells.Clear

[a3] = "Contact Angle (deg)"
[a4] = "Measured At"

sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

For J = LBound(sFilePath) To UBound(sFilePath)
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath(J), ForReading)

    Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream = True
    S = Trim(Replace(TS.ReadLine, Chr(9), Chr(32)))
        For I = 0 To UBound(vLines)
            If InStr(1, S, vLines(I)) = 1 Then
                Select Case I
                    Case 0 '@
                        With rExtract(2, 1)
                            .Value = TimeSerial(Int(Mid(S, 2) / 100), Mid(S, 2) Mod 100, 0)
                            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
                        End With
                    Case 1  '@
                        rExtract(1, 1) = Mid(S, InStrRev(S, " ") + 1)
                        'advance to next column after outputting angle
                        Set rExtract = rExtract(1, 2)
                End Select
            End If
        Next I
    Loop
Next J

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Here is another macro that does NOT require setting a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  It does not use the FileSystemObject, but rather uses built-in VBA routines to read the file. I have been told that it will run more quickly, but I've not tested it myself.  In addition, there could be issues with certain types of data, but they do not seem to exist in your files, and it runs fine on your sample.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetDataFromTextFiles()
    Dim sLines As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim sFilePath
    Dim S As String
    Dim vLines() As Variant
    Dim rExtract As Range
'Hard Coded here but could also use a
'User form to select multiple lines
vLines = Array("@", "Contact Angle")
Set rExtract = [b3]
Cells.Clear

[a3] = "Contact Angle (deg)"
[a4] = "Measured At"

sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)
For J = LBound(sFilePath) To UBound(sFilePath)
    Open sFilePath(J) For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, S
    S = Trim(Replace(S, Chr(9), Chr(32)))
        For I = 0 To UBound(vLines)
            If InStr(1, S, vLines(I)) = 1 Then
                Select Case I
                    Case 0 '@
                        With rExtract(2, 1)
                            .Value = TimeSerial(Int(Mid(S, 2) / 100), Mid(S, 2) Mod 100, 0)
                            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
                        End With
                    Case 1
                        rExtract(1, 1) = Mid(S, InStrRev(S, " ") + 1)
                        'advance to next column after outputting angle
                        Set rExtract = rExtract(1, 2)
                End Select
            End If
        Next I
    Loop
    Close #1
Next J

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: This may seem like a beyond basic question, but how do I implement the code you've provided?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were more familiar with Excel. It is Excel VBA code (visual basic for applications).  Open an Excel workbook. Then, to enter this Macro (Sub), <alt-F11> opens the Visual Basic Editor. Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window. Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and paste the code into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), <alt-F8> opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and <RUN>.  It will allow you to select several text files; and then cycle through the text files to extract the data.

Comment: Before running the macro, from the top line of the VB Editor, select Tools; then References; and select Microsoft Scripting Runtime from the dropdown.

Comment: I think OP wanted python though

Comment: @JohnDorian Hmmm, I thought his goal was to get the data from a text file into Excel for further analysis. So I offered a solution which can be implemented in Excel. If Python MUST be used, then my answer is not appropriate.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you very much, sir. I am not very familiar with Excel past the basics. I'll give your solution a whirl now and see how it works out.

Comment: @JohnDorian If there is a solution in Python, that would be my preferred method. I am not familiar with VBA, and would rather use something that I will use again. Do you know of any Python solutions?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have tried your solution, and apart from changing this line `rExtract(1, 1) = Mid(Trim(S), InStrRev(Trim(S), " ") - 1)` to `rExtract(1, 1) = Mid(Trim(S), InStrRev(Trim(S), " ") + 6)`, it works very well. There seems to be 4 trailing spaces after the angle though, could you help me in eliminating these? I've looked up the trim function, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Matthew If Trim is not working, then those spaces are likely not ASCII space.  Is the data coming from an HTML document or web page?  If so, they are likely NBSP (ASCII code 160).  That would also explain why you had to change the -1.  You should be able to test the line to see what the character is; and also the nature of the spaces within the string -- real char 32 vs char 160.  Then we can devise a solution.

Comment: @Matthew If need be, if you can, post a copy of the file on some public web site, where I can see exactly what's going on.  I just copied and pasted your data from your post; which may not be the same.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The file is here: http://pastebin.com/RCQZBA33. The measurement time is now above the contact angle in the file, so I shuffled your script around a little. Also, the data is coming from a plain text file.

Comment: @Matthew  OK, the character separating the value from the label is a TAB.  So we just need to account for that.  I will repost the modification, and also a change to account for the time occurring first.  Will time always occur first, or do we need to modify so that it could occur first or last?

Comment: The time will occur first from now on, so it shouldn't be necessary to account for the order of occurrence. Thank you again!

Comment: @Matthew And will that separator always be a TAB, or might it sometimes be a SPACE?

Comment: The format should always be the same as the file that I provided. I can't see any reason to why it would be different. On the extremely slim chance that there is a space, is there any way to combine the new statement and the old one?

Comment: I'll post a modification

Comment: We just replace the TAB with SPACE, TRIM the result, and go back to looking for the last SPACE.

Comment: @Matthew  If my last edit satisfies your requirement, please mark it as the answer